# How to determine that a Angular form is tried

Tags: forms, angular

How to determine that a Angular form is tried to submit or not to show invalid fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a form in angular, then the form object contains a boolian property  "submitted". It becomes true when user tries to submit a form.

```
<form #searchForm="ngForm" [ngClass]="{'FormTried':searchForm.submitted}"
        (ngSubmit)="submitData(searchForm)" >
        // your form fields
</form>
```

I used it to add a class for form tried to submit or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #empForm="ngForm" [ngClass]="{'FormTried':empForm._submitted}"
        (ngSubmit)="submitData(empForm)" >
        // added code here
</form>
```

I have used this and this works fine at my end, please try this also.